# Illegal reassignment to import from other .js file

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I want to import score varible from another file called 'scores.js', but It keeps give me an error when running the Svelte apps.

Any Idea how to fix the error?

**store.js**

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export let score = writable(0)
```

**Quiz.svelte**

```
import { score } from './stores.js'

function getANewQuiz() {
    isModalOpen = false
    score = 0
    currentQuestion = 0
    quiz = getQuiz()
  }
```

The errors

```
[!] Error: Illegal reassignment to import 'score'
src\Quiz.svelte (22:4)
20:   function getANewQuiz() {
21:     isModalOpen = false
22:     score = 0
        ^
23:     currentQuestion = 0
24:     quiz = getQuiz()
Error: Illegal reassignment to import 'score'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`score` is a store, so you can use `$score = 0` in your component (or `store.set(0)`).

([Working example](https://svelte.dev/repl/44db012d95a94ed78ddf8c42f8a9945c?version=3.45.0))